# Neo4j Performing shortest path calculations on stored data

Tags: graph, nosql, dijkstra, neo4j

I would like to store the following graph data in the database,

```
graph.makeEdge( "s", "c", "cost", (double) 7 );
graph.makeEdge( "c", "e", "cost", (double) 7 );
graph.makeEdge( "s", "a", "cost", (double) 2 );
graph.makeEdge( "a", "b", "cost", (double) 7 );
graph.makeEdge( "b", "e", "cost", (double) 2 );
```

Then run the Dijskra algorighm from a web servlet, to find shortest path calculations using the stored graph data. Then I will print the path to a html file from the servlet.

```
Dijkstra<Double> dijkstra = getDijkstra( graph, 0.0, "s", "e" );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the actual question or problem is, could you clarify a bit?

There's a [getting started guide](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Getting_Started) that shows basic API usage for Neo4j. If you use it from Java, there's [javadocs online](http://api.neo4j.org/current/). You probably want to index some property on the nodes to find them again, see [indexing](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Indexing_with_IndexService) and [indexing with batchinserter](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Indexing_with_BatchInserter). Graph algorithms like Dijkstra are documented on [the wiki](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Graph-algo). Does that help?

Update: I created a **full example** inspired by this question, located here: http://github.com/neo4j-examples/java-dijkstra. The example includes common Neo4j components and javadocs so it can be used as a starting point for learning more.

Comment: hi paddydub, I finally think I found out what you want. stay tuned for an update of my answer in a while!